# Error entre Vite y React no renderiza el forntend

Tags: reactjs, json, vite

[ERROR] Unexpected end of file in JSON

```
../../tsconfig.json:1:0:
  1 │
    ╵ ^
```

failed to load config from C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
../../tsconfig.json:1:0: ERROR: Unexpected end of file in JSON
at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1646:15)
at C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1058:25
at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1481:45)
at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1056:7)
at C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1085:16
at responseCallbacks. (C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:703:9)
at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:762:9)
at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\nl\Documents\2do Cuat FULLSTACK\NUEVA\tpreact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:679:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)

Comment: Hola fulvia, bienvenido/a, no me manejo en este tema, pero se me ocurre que ante un mensaje del tipo "final de linea inesperado en JSON", deberías mostrar el mismo, para que te puedan orientar hacia una solución, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.